# Tool for Merging Database Scripts

Tags: .net, sql, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Hey all, I'm wondering if anyone has ever used a tool which will take a series of .sql scripts and a manifest file of some sort and merge them into one big .sql file according to the order defined in the manifest?

I'm trying to integrate database change packaging into our automated build and I could write a tool for this but I figured it might already exist.

We use Nant and CruiseControl.NET if there are any solutions specific to that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at DBSourceTools.
http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com.
It's specifically designed to help developers use source control for database changes.
This tool will allow you to baseline your database at a specific point, and create a named version.
All files are scripted to disk, and very easy to add to a version control repository.
Have a look at the patching process for managing release versions.

Comment: nice, thanks. I thought this question was dead and had moved on but its still a problem we need to solve eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I have use Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite Database Edition to do exactly what you are asking for with a very good results.